network printers via GPO (have to use computer account, but would rather user accounts or groups)
I've created a GPO to add a network printer. I would like to have the GPO tied to an active directory group containing users, but I've been unable to make this work.
Instead I notice that if I use security filtering or delegation and add the computer account, it works. when I attempt to do it with a user account (individually or as part of an AD group) the GPO is not applied.
The GPO settings use User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Printers
Is this simply how it works? Am I setting it up wrong, or have something else preventing it from working with user accounts?
Thanks!

In delegation Add Domain Computer, Read only to the GPO
When you remove Authenticated Users from the security group the computer object can't process the GPO, and thus can't apply that user GPO.
It's a change Microsoft did to protect the GPO's store, but it can impact all your users GPO when the Authenticated user group is removed.
